# Template suggestions not showing in markup

Tags: 9

I can't get the Twig file name suggestions in the markup. I'm on D9, ddev and multisite. I have tried all kinds of cache rebuilds.

When running `drush php:eval "var_export(\Drupal::getContainer()->getParameter('twig.config'));"` in the terminal, I get:

```
array (
  'debug' => true,
  'auto_reload' => true,
  'cache' => false,
```

So when clearing caches doesn't help, what is the next step?

Edit: I just found out that it somehow actually shows suggestion deeper into the markup but it should show at least in the beginning at `<html>` too.

These two screenshots are from different projects showing the difference:

[image: What I expect to see]

*^ What I expect to see*

[image: What I see now]

*^ What I see*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turned out that there was a module called MinifyHTML that stripped all comments.